# Installing Anaconda Python in a virtual world without changing global Python version

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good afternoon. I have been learning Virtualenv and Virtualenvwrapper. I then decided I wanted to install Anaconda Python again so I could continue learning how to do data analysis. Then I saw where you can use conda to make a virtual environment for Anaconda. I installed it and told it not to add the path to my bashrc file but then conda was  not recognized. So then I reinstalled and said yes. But now my global python is set to anaconda 3.5 which I do not want. How can I use conda to set up a virtual environment without affecting my global python of 2.7? Thank you.

Comment: `conda` does not affect global installation. Simply turn off activation of conda environment in you bashrc file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix your PATH environment variable so it has the global python directory declared before the anacaonda directory.

Comment: Very nice. Just learned something. That worked great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into a similar issue and I ended up using Docker to manage my Anaconda installation.

https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/minimal-notebook